# JQueryUI 1.10.2 issue with anchor tags

Tags: jquery-ui, anchor

Im using jQueryUI to create dynamic tabs.
Everything was working properly until the point where I added links(relative paths) to navigate between languages. Here's my code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="mitem"><a href="#tabs-0">Home</a></li>
    <li class="mitem"><a href="#tabs-1">The Rooms </a></li>
    <li class="mitem"><a href="#tabs-2">Contact - Location</a></li>
    <li class="mitem"><a href="#tabs-3">Gallery</a></li>
    <li id="languages">
        <a href="../index.html"> <img src="../images/gr.png" alt="Ελληνικά" /></a> 
        <a href="#" onClick="window.location.reload( true );"> <img src="../images/gb2.gif" alt="English" /></a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, i'm currently on directory /root/en/index.html. When i click the first link

```
<a href="../index.html"> <img src="../images/gr.png" alt="Ελληνικά" /></a>
```

it doesn't do anything. Works perfectly though when opening on new tab...
This does not happen from /root/index.html to /root/en/index.html).

Note: When i remove the UI it works but obviously that's not the solution I'm looking for...

UI code inside head tag

```
<!-- JQuery UI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--$(function() {-->
$(document).ready(function () {

    $( "#menu" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

Any syggestions?

Thanks